# How to get detailed error location(character location) in a sinle line python expression

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm struggling with UI that user can input simple expression of underlying data to get some customized output using IronPython.

What I did...

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace SimpleTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        scope.SetVariable("a", new Person("A", 18));
        scope.SetVariable("b", new Person("B", 24));
        object result = null;
        try
        {
            //result = engine.Execute<object>("a.Age + b.Age", scope);
            result = engine.Execute<object>("a.Age + b.Grade", scope);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Error Message : 'Person' object has no attribute 'Grade'
            // TODO HOW TO GET Character Span Location?
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Result:{0}", result);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double Age { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, double age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see the expression passed in `engine.Execute<object>` is invalid because there is no `Grade` prop in the class, so that engine throws exception as expected but it does not contains any information on the character location of text which is good to be shown to user with outstanding color like red.

Any hint to do that ?

I googled but not found any answer for this. Only what I found is about displaying line number in file name information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the `Data` property of the exception to obtain the line info.  The `Data` property contains a dictionary keyed by type objects representing the objects you want to inspect.

You'll want to get the `InterpretedFrameInfo` from the data. It's given as a collection of `InterpretedFrameInfo` objects.  They are essentially the stack trace within the script when it failed.  The `DebugInfo` will contain the information you want.  You could also inspect the `DynamicStackFrame` to inspect the actual contents of the frames.  You could access each collection as an `IReadOnlyList`.

```
if (e.Data[typeof(Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo)]
        is IReadOnlyList<Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo> trace)
{
    // do stuff with trace
}

if (e.Data[typeof(Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicStackFrame)]
        is IReadOnlyList<Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicStackFrame> frames)
{
    // do stuff with frames
}
```

Just keep in mind that it seems that there is some bootstrapping code injected into the scripts, so the `Index` in the frame might be off.  In my case, I'm seeing an offset of `23` for a simple expression.

Comment: I got same value of `offset`(?) 23 but do not understand what's the meaning of it and how to extract exact character span(character index range of the given python expression string).

Is there any more hint?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the `Index` property might mean exactly. At first I thought it was just the offset into the file that the exact position occurs. Line numbers can always be adjusted by using compiler directives if supported. I have no other reason to believe otherwise.